# Azure CosmosDB stored procedure changes the function parameter into smaller case

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to run a stored procedure by passing the query in it. My query is something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE f._self FROM collection f JOIN c IN f.data WHERE (c.Name= 'James') AND (c['DOB'] = '2020-02-02 00:00:00')
```

But after debugging it inside the console of Data explorer, I am getting output like this:

```
select distinct value f._self from collection f join c in f.data where (c.name= 'james') and (c['dob'] = '2020-02-02 00:00:00')
```

It makes the query in smaller case with parameters also. So with this I am not able to query the DB. Why is it behaving like this?

Comment: How are you calling the stored procedure? Through code? Can you share it?

Comment: No I am using Data Explore only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue on my side.Per my experience,there is no such feature(changing your parameter behaviour) in cosmos db SP.

I tested with below SP code:

[image]

Never get smaller case:

[image]

[image]

---

Update Answer:

I tried your latest sql and reproduce your issue on my side.

[image]

And i tested the last sql(contains [Age) and still got lowercase.So,i believe i got correct print resulted from browser cache.

However,based on my below test,i would say that the print console log won't change the sql query result.

Sample data:

[image]

Result:

[image]

It seems that console log print doesn't affect sql query behavior,but it still confused users sometimes.

Comment: Try this: `SELECT DISTINCT VALUE f._self FROM collection f JOIN c IN f.data WHERE (c.Name= 'James') AND (c['DOB'] = '2020-02-02 00:00:00')`

Comment: I don't think it is working fine. I am using it for bulk deletion but it is not deleting anything.

Comment: @Anurag Have you provide correct partition key? Or you just leave the pk empty.

Comment: Partition key is empty.

Comment: @Anurag Please set partition key when you execute SP, please see some explanations in this case:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58718052/delete-documents-from-cosmos-using-query-without-partition-key-specification/58722090#58722090

Comment: @Anurag So when you leave it empty, SP only scan the `""` partition scope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208958/discussion-between-anurag-and-jay-gong).

Comment: @Anurag Hi,if my answer is helpful for you,would you please mark it? Thank you!

Comment: Done. I've one query which I asked in Chat. Can you please help?

Comment: @Anurag Very Sorry for the delay! I can't get some notification from chat room if i leave there. I will post some reply over there.

Comment: In my case, I am not getting any results from collection.queryDocuments() method. Any idea why is it so?

Comment: @Anurag The first thing i can think is you provided wrong partition key if you check the sql is absolutely right and result could be searched normally in the portal UI.

Comment: I am using portal UI only. In the query explorer it is showing results but when I try to run a storedProcedure for query Documents it is giving empty results.

Comment: @Anurag Consider it is related to pk value,please.

Comment: I am using Partition key this time

Comment: I was able to successfully store the data using pk but while deletion it is returning empty results.(no deletion)

Comment: My issue is same as this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003191/documentdb-stored-procedure-querydocument-returns-nothing

Comment: Got it. Yes it was because of pk only. I was missing it one place. Thanks :)

Comment: @Anurag Haha, it is totally resloved by yourself, well done!